# Can we include attachments to iCalendar invitations that are created from an MVC application

Tags: attachment, icalendar

How can we send attachment along with an ics file that are created from MVC application.
We are creating the meeting invitations with data fetched from application in ics format and then downloading for the user to click on it and open in outlook.So can we add an attachment also along with the ics file so that users wen open in outlook will see the attachment along with other details.
Please somebody help.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.1  or https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-1-1-attachment.html, one can ATTACH by referring to the URL of the attachment.

An example given is:

```
ATTACH;FMTTYPE=application/postscript:ftp://example.com/pub/
  reports/r-960812.ps
```

Other examples elsewhere in the spec are:

```
ATTACH:http://example.com/public/quarterly-report.doc
```

or
"The following example specifies an "ATTACH" property with inline
binary encoded content information:

```
 ATTACH;FMTTYPE=text/plain;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY:VGhlIH
  F1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZy4
```

"

or

```
ATTACH;FMTTYPE=application/msword:ftp://example.com/pub/docs/
        agenda.doc
```